# android tiled border around a relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android activity with a relative layout containing a few textview.
I would like to put a border around my relative layout. But as a border I would like use a tiled bitmap. So, tile an image down the left and right of my relative layout and a different image across the top and bottom of my layout.

Is that at all possible?

Comment: Can you give a screen shot of what are you asking to do??

Comment: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html - this might help you

Comment: You can use a relative layout and give background to it and then do padding in it .In this way you will get a border to the layout.